# Reference to ManagementObjectCollection.Count throws invalid class exception

Tags: .net, wmi

In the snippet below, the commented line will throw a System.Management.ManagementException with message "Invalid Class".   However, referencing the Count property **after** iterating the collection works ok.

This code comes from a unit test which was working, and then began failing.  I haven't been able to determine what changed.

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"root\mypath");
scope.Options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM myclass");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
ManagementObjectCollection result = searcher.Get();
//int count = result.Count // throws exception
foreach (ManagementObject mo in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(mo.Path);
}
int count = result.Count // no problem
```

any ideas?

Comment: can you tell me which class and path you are using ?

Comment: It is a custom path and class.

Comment: can you share your path and and class information in details

Comment: I don't want to show the _actual_ text but knowing it would not help anyone on SO diagnose the problem. Don't like "mypath" and "myclass"?  use any other random characters.